# AWS EventBridge with the target AWS Batch with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch, aws-event-bridge

I have created AWS batch environment, job-queue and job definition with the terraform.

Now, I want to trigger the job-definition on a scheduled basis and need to create an AWS EventBridge for that.

```
 resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "job_definition" {
  name = "${var.job_definition_name}"
  type = "container"  
  container_properties = <<CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
{
    "command":  [ "bash", "-c", "if [[ $AWS_BATCH_JOB_ARRAY_INDEX -eq 0 ]]\nthen \n python3 -m app.main;\nelif [[ $AWS_BATCH_JOB_ARRAY_INDEX -eq 1 ]]\nthen \n python3 -m app.semrush;\nelse \n python3 -m app.deepcrawl;\nfi"
    ],
    "image": "${var.docker_image}",
    "memory": 2048,
    "vcpus": 1,
    "volumes": [],
    "environment": [  
        {
            "name": "SFTP_PORT",
            "value": "${var.SFTP_PORT}"
        }        
    ],
    "mountPoints": [],
    "ulimits": []
}
CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
}

module "eventbridge" {
      source = "terraform-aws-modules/eventbridge/aws"
    
      create_bus = false
      create_role = false
    
      rules = {
        crons = {
          description         = "Trigger for a aws batch"
          schedule_expression = "rate(5 minutes)"
        }
      }
      targets = {
        crons = [
          {
            name           = "aws-batch-target-from-eventBridge"
            arn            =  aws_batch_job_definition.job_definition.arn
            input          = jsonencode({"job_queue": "arn_of_batch_queue", "array_size": "2"})
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I am getting an error while applying terraform (terraform plan is working) -

**Creating EventBridge Target failed: ValidationException: Parameter arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:job-definition/image-name-by-tf:1 is not valid. Reason: Provided Arn is not in correct format.
│       status code: 400, request id: xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
│
│   with module.eventbridge.aws_cloudwatch_event_target.this["aws-batch-target-from-eventBridge"],
│   on .terraform/modules/eventbridge/main.tf line 60, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "this":
│   60: resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "this" {**

help needed.

Comment: Urgent or not urgent, would you please add where this is coming from: `arn  = aws_batch_job_definition.job_definition.arn`?

Comment: Please don't post errors as screenshots, but use properly format code blocks.

Comment: Okay @MarkoE , I have changed that line. and Yes, its coming from - arn  = aws_batch_job_definition.job_definition.arn

Comment: I see that, but where is the code for the `resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "job_definition" {}`?

Comment: with the same terraform file.

Comment: @MarkoE , I have edited terraform file in the question.

Comment: Does the job definition get created as expected, showing no errors for that resource?

Comment: yes @MarkoE, Job definition has been created and its there.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found out the `arn` that needs to be passed in case of `AWS batch targets` is the `arn` of the `job queue` in which you want to submit your job
so in my case :

```
  targets = {
    submitJob = [
      {
        name            = "submitJob"
        arn = module.batch.job_queues.high_priority.arn
        attach_role_arn = true
        batch_target = {
          job_definition = module.batch.job_definitions.example.arn
          job_name = "HelloWorld"
          job_attempts = 1
        }

      }
    ]
  }
```